# My code is not printing all the elements of the queue. What is the error?

Tags: java

This is my Queue class. I have implemented it using arrays.

```
public class QueueUsingArray {

private int data[];
private int firstElementIndex;
private int nextElementIndex;
private int size;

public QueueUsingArray() {
    data = new int[10];
    firstElementIndex = -1;
    nextElementIndex = 0;
    size = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

private void checkEmpty() throws QueueEmptyException {
    if (size == 0) {
        QueueEmptyException e = new QueueEmptyException();
        throw e;
    }
}

public int front() throws QueueEmptyException {
    checkEmpty();
    return data[firstElementIndex];
}

public int dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException {
    checkEmpty();
    int output = data[firstElementIndex];
    size--;
    data[firstElementIndex] = 0;
    firstElementIndex = (firstElementIndex + 1) % data.length;
    if (size == 0) {
        firstElementIndex = -1;
        nextElementIndex = 0;
        size = 0;
    }
    return output;
}

public void enqueue(int element) {
    if (size == data.length) {
        int[] temp = data;
        data = new int[data.length * 2];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = firstElementIndex; i < temp.length; i++) {
            data[k] = temp[i];
            k++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < firstElementIndex; i++) {
            data[k] = temp[i];
            k++;
        }
        firstElementIndex = 0;
        nextElementIndex = temp.length;
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        firstElementIndex = 0;
    }
    data[nextElementIndex] = element;
    size++;
    nextElementIndex = (nextElementIndex + 1) % data.length;
}
}
```

Here is my QueueUse class.

```
public class QueueUse {

public static void main(String[] args) throws QueueEmptyException {

    QueueUsingArray q=new QueueUsingArray();

    q.enqueue(10);
    q.enqueue(20);
    q.enqueue(30);
    q.enqueue(40);
    q.enqueue(50);
    q.enqueue(60);
    q.enqueue(70);
    q.enqueue(80);
    q.enqueue(90);
    q.enqueue(100);
    q.enqueue(110);
    q.enqueue(120);
    q.enqueue(130);
    q.enqueue(140);
    q.enqueue(150);
    q.enqueue(160);
    q.enqueue(170);
    q.enqueue(180);
    q.enqueue(190);
    q.enqueue(200);
    q.enqueue(210);
    q.enqueue(220);
    q.enqueue(230);
    q.enqueue(240);
    q.enqueue(250);
    q.enqueue(260);
    q.enqueue(270);
    q.enqueue(280);
    q.enqueue(290);
    q.enqueue(300);

    System.out.println("All elements");

    for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){
        try {
            System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        } catch (QueueEmptyException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
        }
    }
}

}
```

My output is not complete. Output is not showing all the elements in my queue. What is the error. Output is only showing until 140 and not beyond that.

Comment: What do you see when you debug it? More: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Debugging is the first step.

Comment: Why call `q.enqueue()` 30 times? *Suggestion: Use for loop `for(int ictr=10;ictr<=300;i=i+10){q.enqueue(ictr);};`. 30 lines reduced to 1 (or 3 if written on multiple lines).*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have tried debugging. It just comes out of the loop after printing 140.

Comment: @Nimesh I will do that but please tell me solution for my problem first. And thanks.

Comment: @iVvaibhav: That's not debugging. Read the link. Debugging is running the code in the debugger, stepping through it statement by statement, inspecting variables, etc. If you do that, you'll find the error in your logic. Learning to debug effectively is an integral part of learning to program, we all had to learn it, and we all have to do it every day.

Comment: @Nimesh I did as you said...but I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

What can I do now?

Comment: Sorry, that should've been `for(int ictr=10;ictr<=300;ictr=ictr+10){q.enqueue(ictr);};` You can split the loop into 3 rows for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print method does not work because you decrement the size every time you invoke your `dequeue()` method in the for loop. If you are going to use a for loop you should be using a fixed size. Basically in this statement  `( i < q.size() )` as `i` grows `size` decreases. If `i = 0` and `size = 4` the first loop `i` would be 1 and `size` would be 3. Your never going to get to the 0th or 1st element in your queue because by the next loop your already at `i = 2` and `size = 3`.

first you should add a getter for the queue items

```
public int getElementAt(int index){
   return data[index];
}
```

then you can call the method in the for loop for every index in data

```
 int length = q.size();
      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            System.out.println(q.getElementAt(i));
 }
```

If it is not mandatory to do an array implementation, I would suggest using the `Vector` class because it has a better API for a queue. I would also suggest slowly tracing your program every time you have issues and to start with smaller test data sets to make tracing a easier.

```
public class Queue {
    private Vector<String>  data ;

    Queue(){
    data = new Vector();
    }
    public void enqueue(String item){
    data.add(item);
    }

    public void dequeue(){
    data.remove(0);
    }


    public void printQueueItems(){

       int length = data.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            System.out.println(data.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Queue myQ = new Queue();

    myQ.enqueue("hello");
    myQ.enqueue("world");
    myQ.enqueue("!");
    myQ.printQueueItems();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..:)
I just have one question.
I'll have to initialize a variable as the size of queue whenever I want to print the queue elements?

Comment: just figure it out. it depends on your implementation. its just not good practice to use a dynamic size for the loop